# Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}

Tags: grpc-java

I implemented a simple api.

```
    rpc test(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (MyString);
    
    message MyString {
      string value = 1;
    }
```

This is my implementation:

```
    public void test(Empty request, StreamObserver<MyString> responseObserver) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            MyString myString = Mono.just(MyString.newBuilder().setValue("Value "+i).build())
                .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .log()
                .block();
            responseObserver.onNext(myString);
        }
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
```

I use BloomRPC to call the API.

These are the logs:

```
2022-07-19 10:57:19.244  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.21             : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber)
2022-07-19 10:57:19.244  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.21             : request(unbounded)
2022-07-19 10:57:20.250  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-5] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.21             : onNext(value: "Value 1"
)
2022-07-19 10:57:20.251  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-5] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.21             : onComplete()
2022-07-19 10:57:20.253  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.22             : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber)
2022-07-19 10:57:20.253  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.22             : request(unbounded)
2022-07-19 10:57:21.260  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-6] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.22             : onNext(value: "Value 2"
)
2022-07-19 10:57:21.260  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-6] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.22             : onComplete()
2022-07-19 10:57:21.260  WARN 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl          : Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}
2022-07-19 10:57:21.260  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.23             : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber)
2022-07-19 10:57:21.260  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.23             : request(unbounded)
2022-07-19 10:57:22.263  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-7] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.23             : onNext(value: "Value 3"
)
2022-07-19 10:57:22.263  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-7] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.23             : onComplete()
2022-07-19 10:57:22.263  WARN 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl          : Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}
2022-07-19 10:57:22.263  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.24             : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber)
2022-07-19 10:57:22.263  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.24             : request(unbounded)
2022-07-19 10:57:23.267  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-8] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.24             : onNext(value: "Value 4"
)
2022-07-19 10:57:23.267  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-8] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.24             : onComplete()
2022-07-19 10:57:23.267  WARN 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl          : Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}
2022-07-19 10:57:23.267  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.25             : onSubscribe([Fuseable] MonoDelayElement.DelayElementSubscriber)
2022-07-19 10:57:23.267  INFO 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.25             : request(unbounded)
2022-07-19 10:57:24.271  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.25             : onNext(value: "Value 5"
)
2022-07-19 10:57:24.271  INFO 9988 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Mono.DelayElement.25             : onComplete()
2022-07-19 10:57:24.271  WARN 9988 --- [ault-executor-4] io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl          : Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}
```

Expectation: the client sends a request and a streams of 5 single elements is sent with an interval of 2 seconds between each element.

Result: BloomRPC stays in an infinite loading, even after onComplete is called. When onComplete is called, I get the error `Cancelling the stream with status Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Too many responses, cause=null}`

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the proto as follows:

```
rpc test(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream MyString);
```